# Surah Al-Fatihah verses 1:6-7 - Did people in the past already receive Allah's favors?

Tags: quran, tafseer, surat-al-fatihah

In the two last verses of surah Al-Fatihah, verse 1:6 and 1:7, it says,

> *"Guide us along the straight path, the path of those You've bestowed your favors onto them, not those You're furious with, and those who
> are astray".*

The verse specifically described about people whom Allah gave His favors (like sustenances, wealth, health, etc.) as in past tense, which means the favors was already given to them and today we ask the same favors from Him. I think if the verses talking about the path to get the favors (rewards) those not yet given, the verse 7 would have used the word guidance instead.

Am I correct to say that the verses are actually and specifically talking about the favors people in the past used to get in this world during their lifetime from Allah?.

Answer (score 2):

According to Tafsir Al Kashani, Page-8, first paragraph -

> [1:6] ... fix us upon [the path of] guidance
> and empower us to remain upright along the path of oneness, that is, the path of those favoured [by You] with the special favour pertaining to [Your] Mercifulness (raḥīmiyya), which is gnosis, love and guidance, **such as the prophets, the martyrs, the truthful and the friends (awliyāʾ) who have witnessed Him as the First and the Last**, and as the Manifest and the Hidden, and who through the witnessing of the rise of His abiding countenance, became absent from the existence of ephemeral shadow.

---

> ***Did people in the past already receive Allah's favors?***

Yes.

> ***Am I correct to say that the verses are actually and specifically talking about the favors people in the past used to get in this world during their lifetime from Allah?***

No.

This verse is talking about people whom Allah blessed with his mercy. These people were successful in this life and will be successful in the afterlife.

According to the tafsir, examples of this kind of people are - Allah's messengers or prophets, martyrs in religious wars, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I post this as an alternative answer or second opinion I got from someone and somewhere. I'll not mark it as the exact answer yet without examine further.

According to it, there are a couple of times Al-Quran mentioned the word `Sirat Al-Mustaqim (Straight Path)`. Al-Fatihah never said where the path heading to. It's only tell us who walk through it and who else walk the wrong path.

But in surah Yunus verse 10:25, it says that the path takes people who walk through it to the place named `Darussalam (Kingdom of Peace)`. That is where people who walk through it bestowed by Allah with His favors. Referring to verses before and after, the kingdom is no other place than what we call it as `Heaven`.

> *And Allah invites all to the `Kingdom of Peace` and guides whoever He wills to the `Straight Path`.*

Sounds good. But it's not done yet. The question remains, why does it say the favors was already given?.

In surah As-Saffat verse 37:114-120, prophet Musa pbuh and Harun pbuh was also said have earned the favors by Allah. But the word used there is `مَنَنَّا` means something like a gift. The verses clearly step by step describes God's works for them. He gave them His gift, saved them from the disaster, gave them victory, gave them books, showed them the `straight path`, and finally retained them the possesion among people who came after, as the rules of `peace`. I guess that is what `kingdom of peace` mean.

> *And We certainly showed favor to Musa and Harun and delivered them and their people from the great distress. We helped them so it was they who prevailed. We gave them the clear scripture and guided them to the straight path. And We left it for both of them among later people. Peace be upon Musa and Harun.*

Surprisingly, it's all happened on earth here in their lifetime. God helped them won against `Fir'aun`. Now to confirm whether it's true that the people who followed Musa and Harun is among the people in the past who was earned God's favor, let's refer to surah Al-Baqarah verse 2:122.

> *O `People of Israil`! Remember My favors upon you and how I honoured you above the others.*

Comment: There is a difference between guide and invite, Although you could say that the *straight path* leads to home of peace(paradise). [10:25] solely doesn't not exactly/directly say that.

Comment: @AbduRahman how are they not connected? there is an "and" connecting the phrases. the word used in the verse is دَعَا means summon or call up, not actually invite. but the phrases clearly connected